# Kivy launcher not working with numpy

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, numpy, kivy

I have written a Python code using Kivy, however it includes a numpy module. The code runs very well on Linux, Windows. As soon as i transfer the same to my android phone(Using kivy Launcher app) it just crashes down. On removing numpy and then running on android phone works fine.

Is it possible to include numpy and Tkinter? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy Launcher is only capable of running basic Kivy apps and is really meant for demonstration and testing purposes. If you need to use extra libraries such as numpy, you need to build your own APK using [Buildozer](http://buildozer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and python-for-android. Note that the python-for-android toolchain does not work on Windows, so you have to use Linux or OS X.

If you are running on Windows, you can download a VM here: http://kivy.org/#download. Check the VM section at the bottom, you can download the whole 7z archive via HTTP, or you can use the torrent file instead. Otherwise, you can install buildozer with a simple `sudo pip install buildozer`.

You should take a look at the official [Android packaging documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html), but the basics are:

- `buildozer init` - creates a buildozer.spec file
- edit the buildozer.spec, change appropriate keys like package name and version, and add numpy to the requirements (`requirements = kivy,numpy`)
- `buildozer android debug` - builds the APK in debug mode
- `buildozer android deploy` - pushes the APK to a connected device
- `buildozer android run` - starts the app on the connected device
- `buildozer android logcat` - shows the logcat output from the device